# Suggestions that could improve my string splitting function

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to write some basic functions to get the hang of some of it, I decided on making a custom function to split up a string into tokens every time a specific delimiter is reached.

I've made it work successfully, but since I'm new, I'd like to hear from more experienced programmers on if there is a better way to go about it. This is my code:

```
vector<string> split(string const str, string const separator=" ") {
    int str_len = str.length();
    int sep_len = separator.length();
    int current_index {0};

    vector<string> strings {};

    for(int i {0}; i < str_len; ++i) {
        if(str.substr(i, sep_len) == separator) {
            strings.push_back(str.substr(current_index, i-current_index));
            current_index = i + sep_len;
        }
    }

    strings.push_back(str.substr(current_index, str_len-current_index));

    return strings;
}
```

One thing I will say is, I don't like how I had to put

```
strings.push_back(str.substr(current_index, str_len-current_index));
```

this after the entire iteration to get the final part of the string. I just can't think of any different methods.

Comment: Have a look at a [little framework](https://github.com/crusader-mike/parray) I've written in pre-`std::string_view` times. I am still using it... Besides string_view-like functionality it provides efficient versions of string splits and joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`std::string::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to find separators in the string, which is probably much more efficient than your loop that checks for each possible position if the substring at that position matches the separator. Once you have that, you can make use of the fact that if the separator is not found, `find()` returns `std::string::npos`, which is the largest possible value of `std::string::size_type`, so just pass this to `substr()` to get everything from the current position to the end of the string. This way you can avoid the second `push_back()`.

```
vector<string> split(string const &str, string const &separator=" ") {
    string::size_type current_index {};
    vector<string> strings;

    while (true) {
        auto separator_index = str.find(separator, current_index);
        strings.push_back(str.substr(current_index, separator_index - current_index));

        if (separator_index == str.npos)
            break;
        else
            current_index = separator_index + separator.size();
    }

    return strings;
}
```

Note: ensure you pass the input parameters by reference to avoid unnecessary copies being made.